# LibGDX: How can i remove inner actors?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

How can I remove these(on the picture) actors if I only have access to root's Window methods `getChildren()` and `getCells()` ?
I've tried somthing like this:
`removeActor(getCells().get(1).getTable().getCells().get(0).getTable()...getTable());`

But it always return the root Table.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've came to this:

```
Cell<FileChooser> cell = getCells().get(1);
removeActor(cell.getActor().getCells().get(0).getActor());
```

But now it throws nonsense Exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kotcrab.vis.ui.widget.file.FileChooser$11 cannot be cast to com.kotcrab.vis.ui.widget.file.FileChooser
```

How class cannot be cast to its own type?

Comment: Just to the last sentence: the cast is not to its type, but to its anonymous inner class

Answer (score 1):

If you could keep a reference to the `VerticalGroup` when you add it then you could simply call `remove` on that `Actor` to remove it from its parent.

If for some reason you can't get a reference to the node when it's either created or added to the `Stage` `Actor` tree then you can traverse the actors using some sort of path to find the one you want to delete. 
For example; if you know that the "*path*" to the `Actor` that you want to remove is always

```
VisTable/VisScrollPane/VisTable/VerticalGroup
```

then you can use a helper class like this one;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class StageHand {

    public static void removeByPath(Stage stage, Class...classes) {
        removeByPath(stage, new Array<Class>(classes));
    }

    public static void removeByPath(Stage stage, Array<Class> classes) {
        for(Actor actor : stage.getActors())
            removeByPath(actor, 0, classes);
    }

    private static void removeByPath(Actor actor, int index, Array<Class> classes) {
        Class<?> target = classes.get(index);
        if (actor.getClass().equals(target))
        {
            if (index == classes.size - 1)
                actor.remove();
            else {
                if (actor instanceof Group) {
                    for(Actor child : ((Group)actor).getChildren())
                        removeByPath(child, index + 1, classes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd call it something like this

```
StageHand.removeByPath(stage, VisTable.class, VisScrollPane.class, VisTable.class, VerticalGroup.class);
```

If you need to delete based on some other criteria (like `Actor`'s `getName` method for instance), then that would be trivial to achieve as well.

Comment: I updated the question.